# Please, help identifying a classical(?) piano piece

Tags: identify-this-song, piano

Please, help identifying [this](https://coub.com/view/6dhiy) song. (It plays in the background, you might have to unmute the video.) The best Shazam match I got is `'Chopin - 12 Etudes, Op.8: No.9'`. But I can't find the exact part. Sorry, if this is something obvious, I am not very knowledgeable about music.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, Shazam is all over the place. Not only is the piece not Chopin, his Op. 8 are not either of his two sets of etudes, and the Nos. 9 from both etude sets are in completely different keys, neither one of which is the one given in this recording! (Although, to be fair, the digital version in your clip has been transposed.)

This piece is actually the [final movement of Beethoven's famous "Moonlight" sonata, Op. 27 no. 2.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zucBfXpCA6s)